# jsdo.itがサービス終了します

Tags: 討議

ブラウザ上でプログラムを実行できるサービスのひとつである **[jsdo.it](http://jsdo.it/)** が、2019 年 10 月 31 日をもって**サービス終了**し、アクセスできなくなるとのことです。

- [【重要】サービス終了のお知らせ](http://jsdo.it/blog/2019/07/jsdoit-1.html)

このサイトは、スタック・オーバーフローの質問や回答にも時々使われています。素晴らしい投稿がリンク切れと共に価値を失うのは避けたいので、もし jsdo.it を使った投稿があれば、可能な限り内容を復元できるような形に編集できないでしょうか。

- [自分の投稿を他の人が編集できるのはなぜですか?編集はどのように機能しますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

一応検索するとこれだけ出てくるのですが、これで全てでしょうか。

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=jsdo.it

<sub>ところで：第三者が外部サイトのプログラムをコピー＆ペーストする場合、ライセンスの問題がどこまであるのか不明です……。日本の法だと、短いプログラムにはなかなか著作権が発生しないので大抵 OK だとは思うのですが。</sub>

Comment: 一時的なものか分かりませんが、お知らせ以外のトップページ等は既にアクセス出来ないような気がします。

Comment: トップページ等はエラー画面っぽいものが出たり出なかったりする状況が続いているようです。何回かリロードすると読み込めるときがあります。

Answer (score 5):

ひとまず「jsdo.it」で検索して出てきた6件の投稿に関しては、Internet Archiveでアーカイブしたページへのリンクを追加しておきました。

コメントは検索にひっかからないので、漏れはありそうです……。

Comment: ひとまず Stack Exchange Data Explorer で[検索をしてみました](https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/1131747)が、 jsdo.it を含むコメントは見当たりませんでした。